# Matching fact data with de-duplicated dimension records

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I'm starting work on a data warehousing project for a customer that has multiple physical locations with separate instances of the same LOB databases at each location.  There's a good bit of "common" data between the sites, but the systems are siloed, so data that conceptually refers to the same thing has a different representation in the source.

Consider, for example, a product category.  The list of product categories would be identical for each location, but the auto-generated key would differ.  When the data is extracted, staged, and loaded into the corresponding product category dimension table in the warehouse, the categories are effectively duplicated because they have different source system, or "natural" keys.

Clearly, the data needs to be de-duplicated, but what then would become the surrogate key that's persisted on the de-duplicated dimension record?  Keep in mind that data referencing the product category will use the surrogate key from its location of origination.  So, if I have three distinct locations, I'm going to have three different natural keys for the same product category and sales data corresponding to that product category which also references those three natural keys, but ultimately refer to the same conceptual category.  There's a couple of ways I could handle this:

1. If I have three locations, write three distinct surrogate keys to the single dimension record.  This would make matching in the ETL process straightforward, but it's not very scalable because additional locations can and likely will be added.  For every new location that came online, I would then need to add an additional natural key field to every dimension table with such de-duplicated records.
2. Create a lookup table that recorded a mapping between every natural key and its corresponding surrogate key in the corresponding dimension table.  I'm not sure if this approach is very standard nor am I sure about its maintainability.

Any input on how the above-referenced scenario could be handled would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use approach 2.  Imagine one day having hundreds of locations, and you'll see that approach 1 is simply out of the question.

Approach 2 is scalable, and very easy to maintain, since your lookup table will only grow vertically.